# How do I interpolate around a rectangle?

Tags: animation, geometry, interpolation

I want to make a fancy animation where a point travels around a rectangle. I want to find the point's position at a time `t`.

The rectangle is given by `X`, `Y`, `Width` and `Height`.

[image: a rectangle, with a clockwise path around it]

Is there an algorithm for this?

I've used `sin`/`cos` for circles. What's the equivalent approach for rectangles?

Comment: Not a complete answer, therefore a comment. I do not think you can split this buy 1/4 if you do not have a quad, but a rectangle. But what you can do, if you know the max time it should take to go around is: Calculate the circumference s and use the formula s/a=v to calculate your speed v.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll assume your *t* goes from *0* to *1*. (If not, just multiply to scale it appropriately.)

[image: rectangle interpolation]

Figure out what proportion (*0*–*1*) each side is of the perimeter. (*side length / total perimeter*)

To find how much of every side is “filled in” at time *t*, iterate through sides, subtracting their proportions until *t* is depleted to a negative value. That last edge (which caused *t* to go negative) is filled by a proportion of *(side length + remaining) / side length*. The rest are not filled.

To get the exact vector position at *t*, multiply each side's vector by the proportion of that side that is filled, and add them.

This works for any polygon actually!

[image: arbitrary polygon interpolation]

Answer (score 2):

The sine and cosine of t are respectively the y and x coordinate of a point on the circle forming an angle t with the x-axis.  No need for that in a rectangle!  A rectangle is made of four lines.  If `t` goes from `0` to `1`, it reach the point `(px,py)` at `t==0` and to `(qx,qy)` at `t==1` with the line given by:

```
(l(x),l(y)) = (t*qx + (1-t)*px, t*qy + (1-t)*py)
```

if instead of `0` and `1`, you time goes from `t0` to `t1`, you can normalize the time first and then apply the above formula.

```
(l(x),l(y)) = (  ((t-t0)/(t1-t0))*qx + ((t1-t)/(t1-t0))*px, ((t-t0)/(t1-t0))*qy + ((t1-t)/(t1-t0))*py  )
```

Now, for you rectangle, divide in four cases with an `if` for each edge that covers one of the span of time and apply a line movement.

Notice that if your rectangle is axis-aligned, you will always have either the x-value or the y value which is constant.  For instance, for t between `0` and `a/4` (and supposing (X,Y) is bottom left),

```
(l(x),l(y)) = ((4*t/a)*(X+Width) + (1-4*t/a)*(X), Y+Height)
```

Which is also equals to:

```
(l(x),l(y)) = (X + (1-4*t/a)*(Width), Y+Height)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an actual algorithm for this, but I made one myself (Java):

```
int points = 4; // for a rectangle
double progress = 0.0; // 0.0 -> 1.0 (with 1.0 being 100%)
double pp = points * progress; // This calculation would otherwise be done multiple times

int p1 = Math.floor(pp);
int p2 = Math.ceil(pp);

while (p1 >= points) p1 -= points;
while (p2 >= points) p2 -= points;

double tmp = 2 * Math.PI / points;

int p1x = Math.cos(tmp * p1);
int p1y = Math.sin(tmp * p1);
int p2x = Math.cos(tmp * p2);
int p2y = Math.sin(tmp * p2);

double p = pp - Math.floor(pp);

int x = (1.0 - p) * p1x + p * p2x; // between -1.0 and 1.0
int y = (1.0 - p) * p2x + p * p2y; // between -1.0 and 1.0

if (p == 0.0) { // prevent a weird glitch when p = 0.0 (I think this is a glitch)
    x = p1x;
    y = p1y;
}
```

You should transform the `x` and `y` variables to get your animation as big or small as you want (by multiplying) and where you want (adding to / subtracting from x and y).

I haven't tested this code, but I think it should work. This should also work for any polygon with any number of points (you could also use a bit of the code to generate the polygon).

Answer (score 1):

Given :

```
a=total time

perimeter = WIDTH *2 + HEIGTH * 2;
```

Given time `T1` how to get `P` on perimeter (assuming rect position at 0,0)?

```
T1=T1%a; //use mod to have T1<a

distT1 = (T1*Perimeter)/a; //distance traveled in time T1
```

now some easy primary scool geometry and math (that hope you spare me) to obtain `P.x` and `P.y` from `distT1`