# Can I use sin or cos for the non uniform rotation in unity 5?

Tags: c#, javascript, unity

I have few objects which I have to rotate on an ellipsoidal track and speed is changeable at the run time because its a betting game in which racing will be done so speed values will come from the server and I have to handle run time speed as well as the rotation angle at the curved path within the track.

And I would like to clarify one thing that we don't have to give any output to the objects make run just as we play the game the objects start running till the end point without giving an input.

So how do I rotate the objects within the curved area according to change in speed at the run time?

Comment: Would love to know how OP got on, also why I got a downvote?

Comment: Am I right that this question is essentially asking about *how to interpolate around an ellipse at a particular speed*? (Basically an ellipse version of [this rectangle question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/106732/7804)?)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function `sin(t)` this is a nice regular wave.

Now suppose you have some "speed function" `s(t)` which returns any value.

Now `sin(s(t))` has rate of change `s'(t)cos(s(t))`

If `s(t)=t` then we see the rate of change is a nice smooth regular `cos(t)`

---

If we take `s(t)=t^2` then the rate of change becomes `2t cos(t^2)` which as you can hopefully tell becomes "sharper".

I encourage you to experiment with such things in a spreadsheet and plot a graph.

Comment: Have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Thanks but why did u do feedback as downvote to me?

Comment: @ShraddhaPatel it wasn't me. (I've just +1ed you, if I was the downvoter I couldn't have done that)

Comment: Thanks a lot...I thought that u did that by the way thank you so much for reply ;)

Comment: @ShraddhaPatel please do give me the tick if it helped (I've lost points for this answer because someone downvoted)

Comment: Sir u said me to it but if I have non uniform speed then? Then what would I do in that case? And speed changes at every 3 seconds.