# Shader value remap - Blend Falloff

Tags: opengl, shaders, directx, glsl, hlsl

I would like to know if there's a way to remap a value that goes from 0 to 1 constantly like this.

[image]

Into those values (those are examples).

[image]

This might be some function transformation but I can't find the way to do that. I've tried using a lookup texture but in my opinion this is not the best solution.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dari said, the [**smoothstep**](http://www.fundza.com/rman_shaders/smoothstep/) function is the best solution to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so what you have is something like `f(t)=(colour from gradient)` as `t` goes from `0` to `1`

This gives a nice smooth gradient, Where as if you take an auxiliary function, say `a(t)=t^2` you'll notice this also goes between 0 and 1 (as `t` goes from `0` to `1` but it starts much slower then gets much faster.

You can compose the two, by using `f(a(t))` this "alters the speed" that `t` changes if you will.

---

If `f(t)` has gradient `1` (uniformly, as the gradient increases at a constant rate, it must be 1 to go from the far ends of the colour gradient over a time of "1")

then `f(a(t))` has gradient `a'(t)f'(a(t))` which if `a(t):=t^2` gives a rate of change of:
`2t` which at `t=0.25` has gradient `0.5` (half the rate of change of the "normal" gradient) and at `t=0.75` it has a gradient of `1.5` which is 50% faster than the usual one.

Using different `a(t)` you can get different effects

(someone else was asking about altering rates of change earlier, [Can I use sin or cos for the non uniform rotation in unity 5?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108732/can-i-use-sin-or-cos-for-the-non-uniform-rotation-in-unity-5/108733#108733) but for some reason I got a comment-less downvote, this is a similar question right?)

---

### !!!CAUTION!!!

Take a function like:

```
f(t) = { 5t              if 0<= t < 0.1
       { 0.5+5(t-0.1)/9  if 0.1 <= t <= 1
```

This will have a shape like:

```
1                  1
|             ___/ |
|        ____/     |
|   ____/          |
|  /               |
| /                |
|/                 |
+------------------+
0                  1
```

It'll rise really sharply as we go from 0 to 0.1 then increase slowly to 1.

If we differentiate this we get:

```
f'(t) = { 5    if 0<= t < 0.1
        { 5/9  if 0.1 <= t <= 1
```

Which has a graph something like this:

```
|
|   _________
|
|___
|
+------------
```

Notice the jump, it is NOT continuous, which will be apparent in the result.

Don't fret though, there are plenty of "smooth" functions to choose from!

Comment: Thank you for your very precise answer, I also found that the smoothstep function could help me do this.